# How to restrict number of users are limited to 10 requests/minute for api call

Tags: magento-1.8, api, customer, php-5.4

I have created custom `api` for `customer` module with help of [this Link](http://greladesign.com/blog/2010/09/13/how-to-create-magentos-custom-api/). I want to restrict the number of users to access this `api`.

Now how Can I restrict number of users are limited to access request/min.

**Can you give Any suggestions/Idea on this?**

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the first request comes in you could store the current time and request number in session. The way you implement this API should have a session associated with it.

Here is some untested code to give you an idea:

```
$session = Mage::getSingleton('api/session');
$requestNumber = $session->getRequestNumber();
if(!isset($requestNumber)){
$session->setInvokeTime(now());
$session->setRequestNumber(1);
}else{
    $session->setRequestNumber($session->getRequestNumber() +1);
}
if($session->getRequestNumber() == 11){
    if(($session->getInvokeTime() -now())  < 60) {
        return;
    }else{
        $session->setInvokeTime(now());
        $session->setRequestNumber(1);
    }
}
```

Comment: ,thanks you. I will get back to you If i have any queries on this.